# Javascript with Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, coffeescript

I have everything working on my local host with javascript/coffeescript.

But when I transfer it to heroku.  The only javascript asset I see is application-2094230948230948.js (not the exact number).  Inside of that is compressed javascript.  I can't find my [scaffold].js which my coffeescript should be compiling down to.

My javascript console in chrome isn't finding certain functions/libraries.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's the asset pipeline at work. It combines all the javascript into one single file when you're in production.

Be sure to add your custom libraries in the `application.js` manifest file using `//= require`